# Please let me know the version where the input field has an onSubmit event for the first time in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, event-handling

My Unity Version is 2018.2.7f1
I want use Inputfield.onSubmit Event
but there is no event such that

So I wonder from what version Inputfield.onSubmit Event was made

Answer (score 1):

Since Unity `2019.2` the entire `UnityEngine.UI` was moved to a [package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.InputField.html) which is by default pre-installed.

There definitely already exists [`onSubmit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.InputField.html#UnityEngine_UI_InputField_onSubmit) as an event.

Up until version [2019.1](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html) it doesn't appear in the API at least (which doesn't necessarily mean it didn't exist - but it is quite probable that not)

---

In general your version `2018.2.7f1` is from `September 6, 2018`!

On longer ongoing projects you should definitely try and regularly keep up with the latest LTS version (currently [2022.3.8](https://unity.com/releases/editor/qa/lts-releases)). Be aware that jumping now might of course come with some issues and changed APIs - but it is still worth doing some incremental upgrades. Yet alone because of performance improvements and bug fixes etc.

---

Also in general the text related components from `UnityEngine.UI` (`Text`, `InputField` (which uses `Text`), `Dropdown` etc) are also legacy now. You should switch over to [`TextMeshPro`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0/manual/index.html) and according [`TMP_Inputfield`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html).